# SQL Merge replication : How to tell what has changed.

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a query regarding the merge replication. Is there any stored procedure which gives me exactly the column values that have been changed at the server, because of which the row will be replicated to the subscriber in the next replication session ?

I have looked at this link http://www.replicationanswers.com/Script9.asp which allows me to get the info of all the rows that need to be replicated. But i want to know the specific columns that have changed for these rows.

Comment: Guys any suggestions ? hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference sys.sp_showlineage and possibly sys.sp_showcolv, but you are heading down a path of system internals which requires a great deal of learning and understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help . With the hint given by you i did some searching and found the article [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28048/how-to-understand-what-columns-have-changed-in-merge-replication) . Helped me identify the columns . Thanks.

Comment: **OFFTOPIC** Can you have a look at the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194090/merge-replication-with-static-filters-does-not-delete-from-the-subscriber-data And give your comments/Suggestions. Have posted it last week yet haven't received any comments. Help will be really appreciated.